# New instance not terminating Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following code why is it that calling the shutDown() method using a new instance doesn't stop the while loop but when I call the shutDown() method using the existing instance of Processor class then the loop terminates?

It is my understanding ( from this link  [difference between processes and threads](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/java/differences-between-thread-and-process-in-java.php)) that threads are subsets of processes and all threads within a process share the same heap, memory etc. Now if the 'private boolean running' variable is shared between all threads(since it is a class variable) then why doesn't the new Processor instance new Processor().shutDown(), change said variable to false?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Processor extends Thread {
    private  boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            System.out.println(" hello ppl");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        running = false;

    }
}


public class App1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Processor p1 = new Processor();
        p1.start();

        System.out.println("press enter to stop");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();


        p1.shutDown(); // THIS WORKS
        //new Processor().shutDown(); // THIS DOESNT!!


    }

}
```

Comment: Your error lies with the `private boolean running` variable – it is a class instance field (each instance of `Processor` has its own) and not a class field (all instance share the same one). To use a class field as you intended, you have to declare it `static`. However, you must synchronize the access to the shared space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Processor().shutdown();
```

wont work because where the threat is started?

For a thread to run, first of all, it need to be started. The above code is creating a new thread, but doesn't start it!

Modify it like,

```
Processor p = new Processor();
p.start();
p.shutdown();
```

Try like above.. It will work.

In case you want the same thread to be stopped, assign the boolean running globally, or make it static like the following..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Processor extends Thread {
    private static boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            System.out.println(" hello ppl");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        running = false;

    }
}


public class App1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Processor p1 = new Processor();
        p1.start();

        System.out.println("press enter to stop");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();


        //p1.shutDown(); // THIS WORKS
        new Processor().shutDown(); // THIS WILL WORK NOW!!


    }
```

But this will stop all the instances of the running thread. Good practice is the former! Your solution is the latter!

Comment: Thank You. It was a small mistake about not adding the static keyword. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Please mark the answer if my solution helped you. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You tries to change instances variable. Every instance have its own set of variables. In your case you should use class variables with modificator `static` - then all your threads will down after `.shotDown()` call.

PS please learn Java before trying to use it. It is basics of language and programming using this language.

Comment: oh. Thanks. I had forgotten to add the static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance of the class with `new Processor()`, it gets its own "space" for variables. That has nothing to do with Threads, its just object orientated. Every instance of a class has its own variables.